# Where is the original price set in sales order item table?

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2.2

In `quote_item` table we don't have a column `original_price`. So when and how `sales_order_item` table get the original_price value.

Post order we are seeing original_price as 0 in admin sales order view page. Unable to locate where the original price is set as 0 in the sales_order_item table.

Anybody have idea about this?

Comment: Did you find answer for this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

In our case we were overwriting the original price in an observer, which did not come through to the order item.

Setting a breakpoint in `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item::setOriginalPrice` you find that it is called on order by `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem::convert`

The original price is already in the `$item` passed to that function.

In my case the `original_price` is taken from the `base_original_price`, which is set to the catalog price.

This is happening in `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal::_initItem` which calls `$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty());`

An option would be to overwrite the `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem::getBaseOriginalPrice` and overwrite the original price with the `custom_original_price`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem with orders that were being imported programmatically and it was instructive to find out where that data is supposed to come from.

A quote item gets [converted to an order item](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/ToOrderItem.php) by `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem::convert()`. It does this by getting a [list of attributes to copy from the fieldset](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/etc/fieldset.xml#L219-L221) and then [calling their getters](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject/Copy.php#L218). Calling the [getter](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/AbstractItem.php#L503-L517) `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem::getOriginalPrice()` causes it to get calculated from `base_original_price`.

So the next question is where does `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem::getBaseOriginalPrice()` come from? That attribute also gets [copied from the quote item](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/etc/fieldset.xml#L258-L260), but it is also not a value that is persisted in the database, so how does it get set on the quote item then? Turns out that during `$quote->collectTotals()`, it gets [calculated and set on the quote item](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php#L141) by `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal::_calculateRowTotal()`.

I hope that helps you identify where the breakdown is occurring, and be sure that `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::collectTotals()` is being called before the quote is converted to an order.